# Find common SNPs in multiple VCF files

Tags: vcf, snp, variants

I have 3 VCF files.

```
A1.vcf
A2.vcf
A3.vcf
```

I want to get the common SNPs that are present in all these three files. And output must be in vcf format.

output:

```
common_A.vcf
```

Comment: Do you mean SNPs in terms of shared variants or shared positions?

Comment: google intersect or overlap between VCF files, -> bcftools isec

Comment: I have tried isec, but the produced files do not contains the VCF file contains common file

Answer (score 3):

A potential solution is to compress and index the files using [bgzip](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html) and [tabix](http://www.htslib.org/doc/tabix.html), then use [bcftools isec](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html#isec) to find SNPs common to all three files, e.g.

````
for files in A1.vcf A2.vcf A3.vcf
  do
  bgzip "$files"
  tabix "$files"
done

bcftools isec -n=3 -c all -o all_common_SNPs.vcf A1.vcf.gz A2.vcf.gz A3.vcf.gz
```
````

Comment: Hi @Jared_mamrot - can you please explain `-c all` I've seen `-c none` `-c all/both` I'm unable to understand/follow this flag.

Comment: As I understand it @Death-Metal, if you have two vcfs, one with the variant T->CCA at chr1 pos10001 and the other with the variant T->A at chr1 pos10001 , the `-c all` flag will treat these as a 'common to the two files' (i.e. there is a variant at chr1:10001 and it will be 'kept' when you isec). If you specify `-c none`, the REF/ALTs need to match exactly (i.e. both vcfs need to be e.g. T->A to be kept). With `-c both`, the variant must be the same type e.g. both SNPs or both INDELs, regardless of the ALTs. More details here: https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html#common_options